# count unique cases that fall within overlapping posixct ymd hms intervals by the second

Tags: r

have a posixct start time and end time and am trying to count the unique cases of items that have overlapping times by the second

cant change the posixct ymd hms using lubridate or it changes the hms to an odd time. the data was in mm:ss originally as a character. I added 00: to the beginning using strings manipulation but cant get into proper hh:mm:ss for a dplyr or loop that works

```
`head(Fish_20180424_001_New) #my data table

      Survey ID          Clip ID                 Species         Enter Frame          Exit Frame
1: 20180424 001 20180424 001 001 Catostomus occidentalis 2019-05-23 00:01:03 2019-05-23 00:01:08
2: 20180424 001 20180424 001 001   Ptychocheilus grandis 2019-05-23 00:01:16 2019-05-23 00:01:18
3: 20180424 001 20180424 001 001 Catostomus occidentalis 2019-05-23 00:01:48 2019-05-23 00:01:52
4: 20180424 001 20180424 001 001 Catostomus occidentalis 2019-05-23 00:02:04 2019-05-23 00:02:06
5: 20180424 001 20180424 001 001                   Unkn. 2019-05-23 00:02:06 2019-05-23 00:02:08
6: 20180424 001 20180424 001 001   Ptychocheilus grandis 2019-05-23 00:02:07 2019-05-23 00:02:11      

setkey(Fish_20180424_001_New, Species, `Enter Frame`, `Exit Frame`)
vecTime <- seq(from=Fish_20180424_001_New$`Enter Frame`[1],to=Fish_20180424_001_New$`Exit Frame`[nrow(Fish_20180424_001_New)],by=1)
res <- data.frame(time=vecTime)

for(i in 1:length(unique(Fish_20180424_001_New$Species)) ) { 
addz <- array(0,length(vecTime))
remz <- array(0,length(vecTime))

Fish_20180424_001_New_Final <- Fish_20180424_001_New[J(unique(Fish_20180424_001_New$Species)[i]),] # Subset a certain species

startAgg <- aggregate(Fish_20180424_001_New_Final$`Enter Frame`,by=list(Fish_20180424_001_New_Final$`Enter Frame`),length)
endAgg <- aggregate(Fish_20180424_001_New_Final$`Exit Frame`,by=list(Fish_20180424_001_New_Final$`Exit Frame`),length)
addz[which(vecTime %in% startAgg$Group.1 )] <- startAgg$x
remz[which(vecTime %in% endAgg$Group.1)] <- -endAgg$x

res[,c( unique(Fish_20180424_001_New$Species)[i] )] <- cumsum(addz + remz)
```

}

```
res2<-res%>%filter(time < "2019-05-23 00:20:01")

max(res2$`Catostomus occidentalis`)
max(res2$`Micropterus sp`)
max(res2$`Micropeterus salmoides`)
max(res2$`Morone saxatilis`)
max(res2$`Ptychocheilus grandis`)
max(res2$Unidentified)
max(res2$Unkn.)
```

the vecTime only has a length of 66 and seems to start at the right spot (00:01:03) but ends early where the first start time overlaps an end time (02:06)

need to get the appropriate sequence which should end at the length of the last entry in the end time which is 00:51:27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by changing the second portion of the vecTime argument (to=) to max(exit frame), I was able to achieve the appropriate answer and eliminate issues where start and stop times overlap.

still open to exploring other answers, if anyone feels like posting additional thoughts